Apache Ignite- Does IgniteCache.lock(key) returns same Lock object every time it invoked?
Does IgniteCache.lock(key) is distributed, singleton object for each supplied key?
Is it same as hazelcast IMap.lock(key) ??
I want to use lock objects without storing an entry into Cache.


I want to use lock objects without storing an entry into Cache

You can do that. Non-existent keys can be locked, and this will prevent others taking the lock on that key. It is a distributed lock.

Does IgniteCache.lock(key) return same Lock object every time it invoked?

No, it is a new Java object every time. Only one of those objects across the entire system can hold a lock at a given moment.

If you want a lock without referencing a cache, you might also want to consider a Reentrant Lock.
